# Insert a Record from one instance of SQL server DB to Other instance SQL Server DB

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two servers named jcpcsql and gppcsql. Both have same tables naming and structure.

I want to insert a record from jcpcsql to gppcsql.

```
Server : jcpcsql
table : dbo.siox22
database name: mydat
data:
ID   Type   Name   list  userinfo
22   2xc    asset   43    e43


Server: gppcsql
database name: mydat1
table: dbo.siox22
data: 

use gppcsql

 Insert into mydat1.dbo.siox22 

 from jcpcsql.mydat.dbo.siox22
```

I'm not sure how to get that particlar record inserted. i tried above query, i know that's actually wrong.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you do a selection of the target server's table at the source server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Insert into mydat1.dbo.siox22 

 Select * from jcpcsql.mydat.dbo.siox22
```

Comment: I need a particular row to insert

Comment: You can add where to select